# Mais uma sala de chat global. Qual a tecnologia para esse tipo de aplicação?

Tags: google-maps, maps, chat

Nesse [link](https://round.io/chat) temos mais uma sala de chat global. O interessante é que ela parece usar google map. ALguem poderia esclarecer qual a tecnologia e téchnica, envolvida na criação de uma aplicação como essa?

Sei que parece uma questão meio subjetiva e com chances de ser fechada, mas é uma dúvida de qualquer jeito.

Comment: Provavelmente é [google-maps-api](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=pt-br) combinado com uma tecnologia própria que usa WebSocket. Resumindo nem tudo é "pronto", a maioria das coisas são "criadas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente é javascript e api do GoogleMaps, se verificar o código fonte verá que é apenas Javascript, agora a parte backend, pode ser PHP, RUBY, JAVA, NODE.JS, linguagem de Banco de dados NoSQL, ou mesmo relacional, mas creio que seja apenas javascript com uso de sockets.